# FLTK - Compile Multiple .cpp's - Linux

Tags: c++, linux, fltk

For simplicity, I have reduced my problem to a minimal working example.

I begin with a file, `blah.cpp`, that is very simple.

```
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Fl_Window* win = new Fl_Window(100,100,100,100,"Title");
    win->show();
    return Fl::run();
}
```

To compile it, I type into my terminal (while in the directory of the file `blah.cpp`)

```
fltk-config --compile blah.cpp
```

Which works perfectly fine. I simply type `./blah`, and the 100 pixel window is shown on the screen. However, my issue arises once I would like to expand to more than one file - namely, `blah.cpp`,`head.h`,and `blah2.cpp`.

```
/* head.h */
#ifndef HEAD
#define HEAD

#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>

class My_Window{
    public:
        My_Window(int,int);
        bool open();
        ~My_Window(){ 
            delete win;
        }
    private:
        Fl_Window* win;
};

#endif

/* blah2.cpp  */
#include "head.h"

My_Window::My_Window(int w, int h):{
    win = new Fl_Window(w,h);
    win->show();
}

bool My_Window::open(){
    return Fl::run();
}

/* blah.cpp */
#include "head.h"

int main() {
  Window win(300,300);
  return win.open();
}
```

My question is, how would I compile this project (blah.cpp and blah2.cpp) with the terminal? My initial guess would be to place everything in the same directory and do something like

```
fltk-config --compile *.cpp
```

or

```
fltk-config --compile "*.cpp"
```

but neither of those work. How would I go about compiling this?

**[SOLUTION]**

I ended up solving this right after I finished typing it. I'll leave it up since I've seen it appear numerous times on the internet.

I did away with the `fltk-config` command, and stuck with the regular `g++`:

```
g++ -std=c++11 blah.cpp blah2.cpp -o blah -lfltk
```

And with that it worked! The executable of the program was then created with the title `blah`! Of course, the `-std=c++11` line only means to follow the c++11 standard, so that isn't completely necessary for my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fltk-config --compile <file.cc>` is made to be a convenience option when you have a single-file project. It compiles and links your application.

If you have multiple files, say *main.cc* and *account.cc* your best option is to do the compilation first, and then link them all together.

Something like (note I have requested the images library too):

```
g++ `fltk-config --cxxflags` main.cc
g++ `fltk-config --cxxflags` account.cc
gcc -o myapp `fltk-config --use-images --ldflags` main.o account.o
```